# Can't get enumeration on library (undefined reference staticMetaObject)

Tags: c++, qt, enums, shared-libraries

I have an application which uses a Qt library (shared library). On my library, I have a class with several enumerations which I want use on main application. 
I build my library project without problem but I when I build main application project, I have the error :

```
moc_myapp.cpp:-1: erreur : undefined reference to `MyClass::staticMetaObject'
```

I didn't find information about this error.

This is my Biblio .pro

```
QT       -= gui

QT += quick multimedia network

TARGET = MyBiblio
TEMPLATE = lib

DEFINES += MYBIBLIO_LIBRARY

SOURCES += myBiblio.cpp 
HEADERS += myBiblio.h\
        myBiblio_global.h \
        myClass.h
```

This myClass.h :

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

#include <QObject>

class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum MyEnumeration {Enum1, Enum2, Enum3};
    Q_ENUMS(MyEnumeration)
};
#endif // MYCLASS_H
```

and myApp .pro :

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick multimedia network widgets sql xml

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    myapp.cpp 

HEADERS += \
    myapp.h 

RESOURCES += qml.qrc 

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/pathTo/build-MyBiblio_Qt_5_2_1/release/ -lMyBiblio
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/pathTo/build-MyBiblio_Qt_5_2_1/debug/ -lMyBiblio

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/pathTo/MyBiblio
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/pathTo/MyBiblio
```

On myapp.cpp, I use enumeration define of the library :

```
MyClass::MyEnumeration
```

and i include "myclass.h"

i use Qt 5.2 under Windows.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Don't shared libraries require exporting/importing symbols on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a shared library that you would like to link against, then you need to ensure that the symbols that are going to be used outside the library are properly exported when the library is created. And subsequently imported when you are linking against the library. This can be done using `Q_DECL_EXPORT` and `Q_DECL_IMPORT`

You already have the following define in your lib pro:

```
DEFINES += MYBIBLIO_LIBRARY
```

Modify your myClass.h as follows:

```
#if defined MYBIBLIO_LIBRARY
 #define MYBIBLIO_LIBRARY_DLLSPEC Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
 #define MYBIBLIO_LIBRARY_DLLSPEC Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

class MYBIBLIO_LIBRARY_DLLSPEC MyClass : public QObject
{
```

Please, read [How to create a library with Qt and use it in an application](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application) for more information.